# Seeking a local video using currentTime doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video, html5-video

I'm trying to seek ahead 10 seconds when the spacebar is pressed using HTML5 video.  It works as expected when using an online video source, but when I download the [video](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.mp4) (right-click and save video as), and reference it from my harddrive, it instead resets the video to the beginning when I press the spacebar.  The problem seems to be specific to Chrome; it works as expected in Explorer and Firefox.

Comment line 5 and uncomment line 6 to use local source and show the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <video id="video" controls tabindex="0" autobuffer preload>
            <source type="video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"" src="http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.mp4"></source>
            <!-- <source type="video/mp4; codecs=&quot;avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2&quot;" src="Chrome_ImF.mp4"></source> -->
        </video>

        <script>
            var video = document.getElementById("video");
            document.addEventListener( "keydown", onKeyEvent, true);

            function onKeyEvent(event) {

                if (event.keyCode == 32)  // "space"
                {
                    if(event.type == "keydown")  // seek forward 10s and play video
                    {
                        video.currentTime = 10;
                        video.play();
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Tested with Chrome 45, Internet Explorer 11 and Firefox 41 with Windows 8.1.

Comment: is there any special reason to use `&quot;` instead of `"` ?

Comment: The &quot there from some sample code I used.  I changed them to double quotes and it worked the same way.  I updated the code and replaced instances of &quot with ".

Comment: Let me give a try to your code.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with Chrome `Version 45.0.2454.99 m` the video rewinds and play at 10'' with both local and remote file. With Firefox I noticed that while playing the local file, the video goes to 10'' but it doesn't play automatically.

Comment: I just now repeated the test, including downloading the video from the link in my post.  The remote video works fine, but the local video is still resetting to the beginning when I hit the spacebar.  I have since upgraded to windows 10 and my Chrome version is 45.0.2454.101 m.

Comment: I'm also using w10, what's your full chrome version ?

Comment: See edit above for chrome version.  Also, if it helps, I'm using python 3.4.3 and running ```python -m http.server``` to allow me to load my .html file with ```http://localhost:8000/examples/videoTest.html``` and access local files from a web browser.

Comment: I don't think the python server is to blame for this. I couldn't see the full chrome version above.

Comment: Chrome 45.0.2454.101 m.

Comment: You may want to report a Chrome bug https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en

Comment: I reported the bug in Chrome.

Comment: Can you provide the link to your bug report? I can confirm the issue.

Comment: Having the same problem chrome Version 55.0.2883.87

Comment: Same problem with `HTMLMediaElement.currentTime = ev.target.value;`. Seeking causes time to restart. But in other browsers seeking works fine.